# how can I import a path to work with in my App?

Tags: c++, file, wxwidgets, explorer

suppose you are making an image editor by **wxWidgets** and you want to choose the file to work in. you must make the *import* or *open* button to choose the image
you click it and the explorer pop up and you choose the file
how can developpe this operation in c++?

Comment: please check the dialog sample on how to do it.

Comment: Use [wxFileDialog](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cmndlg.html#overview_cmndlg_file)